# What is the proper structure of a nodejs/express backend to retrieve mysql data and send to react

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning full-stack development and have successfully completed a few courses, primarily learning nodejs, express, react and mysql.  I feel like I have a decent understanding of the fundamentals.  However, I am a bit lost on how I **smartly** design the backend server / API that interacts with MYSQL.

Is there a common design pattern for creating objects that wrap up the database functionality?  For instance, if I am retrieving configuration data from a database to display in the react front-end, is there a smart way to wrap up those operations in classes -- other than simply using app.get/app.post functions in the nodejs/express server?

Answer (score 0):

From the Backend perspective, you might want to consider the following structure, although it varies depending on how one wants to use Node.js:

1. app.js
2. routes/ (export routers grouped by domain/ function)
3. views/ (if any)
4. database/init (connection pool initializations)
5. repository/ (database functions)
6. controllers/ (business logic)
7. config/ (default environment variables/ config settings)

In the case of database initialization, make sure the DB object is created in a single location and only once when the app is started and is being reused across all database calls.

Whether or not to use classes depends on how you end up using Javascript/ Typescript with Node.js (OOPS or Functional way). In the case of OOPS, it makes sense to create a Singleton Class and re-use the database object.